# Taking portions of an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Suppose I have a 4 by 4 matrixes like this:

```
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
```

User enters a random portion number,for the sake of simplicity let it be 2.
I want to create 2x2 matrixes inside of the big matrix.

```
Submatrice1:
1 1
2 2

Submatrice2:
3 3
4 4

Submatrice3:
1 1
2 2

Submatrice3:
3 3
4 4
```

And then i want to replace

every number in submatrice 1 with a

every number in matrice 2 with b

every number in matrice 3 with

every number in matrice 4 with d

Last form of matrix:

```
a a c c
a a c c
b b d d
b b d d
```

And this should be generalized for n*m case.

I've no idea about where to begin.I'd appericate any ideas.

Comment: How would you resolve ambiguities? There are 3 sets of `[1 1, 2 2]` and 3 sets of `[3 3, 4 4]`? How were they chosen in your example?

Comment: I don't think there's enough information, you haven't outline border cases.  You have a very special circumstance where n is not only a square, but a square that can be composed of 4 squares.  We need more problem information to generalize this.

Comment: This means it doesn't matter what was in the matrices before the start, right? It depends just on the size.

Comment: What should the result be if the portion number doesn't divide evenly into the big matrix. For instance in the example above if the portion number was 3 what would the resulting matrix look like?

Comment: You can begin by breaking all of this into smaller problems. Then, tackle each smaller problem in turn, breaking it down again if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with an index-based calculation, as it seems the initial content doesn't matter.

```
/* Input: matrix and the size (2 in the example) */


/* The number of blocks. */
int block_height = (matrix.length + size/2) / size;

for(int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
  for(int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
    int block_row = row / size;
    int block_col = col / size;

    /* If we count up -> down, right -> left */
    char block_index = block_col * block_height + block_row;

    matrix[row][col] = 'a' + block_index;
  }
}
```

This will start placing non-alfabet characters once the alfabet runs out, though.

It should do the following for 2, I don't really know if this side case if what you thought of.

```
[ 1 1 1 1 1 ]       [ a a d d g ]
[ 2 2 2 2 2 ]       [ a a d d g ]
[ 3 3 3 3 3 ]  -->  [ b b e e h ]
[ 4 4 4 4 4 ]       [ b b e e h ]
[ 5 5 5 5 5 ]       [ c c f f i ]
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the behavior he is looking for, though he picked a very simple(perhaps the most simple possible) example to show us, so it's hard to be sure.

Comment: It's indeed very well possible he meant something different. I'll just leave this here in case I guessed his question correct.

Comment: Now i notice this is exactly what i wanted.Ty mate

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
someArray[4] = your input.
someBigArray[n][m];

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++) {

        if(i < n/2) 
            if(j < m/2)
                someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[0] + offsetASCIIToA)
            else 
                someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[1] + offsetASCIIToA)
        else 
            if(j < m/2)
                someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[2] + offsetASCIIToA)
            else 
                someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[3] + offsetASCIIToA)
     }
}
```

This is a pseduo code solution.  You can adjust it for boundary cases and what not.  I would just let integer division decide your border cases, this makes the most sense and is easiest, but you can modify the logic in minor ways to make it behave like you want.  You could also include the logic in multiple for loops, using combinations if i = n/2, j = m/2, i < m/2 so on and so fourth.  This is mildly more performant(less branching), but a bit more code.  Each solution is O(m * n).  The solution below outlines this possible logic.

```
for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m/2; j++)
        someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[0] + offsetASCIIToA)

for(int i = n/2; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < m/2; j++)
        someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[1] + offsetASCIIToA)

for(int i = 0; i < n/2; i++)
    for(int j = m/2; j < m; j++)
        someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[2] + offsetASCIIToA)

for(int i = n/2; i < n; i++)
    for(int j = m/2; j < m; j++)
        someBigArray[n][m] = (char)(someArray[3] + offsetASCIIToA)
```

All you have to do now is figure out your conversion of values in someArray to their appropriate character value.  Just look up ASCII tables for this information, and use casting.

NOTE: this is making some assumptions about your problem.  Your example, I feel, may be particularly poor.  How you modify this for if your array is potentially 5 values could be defined too many ways for me to provide insight into how I would solve it.